# LikeButton UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem. When I click the button like, the like count refresh with the number of likes but when I scroll the `UITableView` and return to the post , the `likecount` return to the previous value. Example: I have 1 like, I click like and the `likecount` is 2 but when I scroll the `UITableView` and return to the post I have again 1 likes. Why?

```
@IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    self.like.isEnabled = false
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let keyPost = ref.child("posts").child(self.postID)
    keyPost.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let post = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            var likes = post["likes"] as! Int
            likes = likes+1
            let update = ["likes" : likes]
            self.likecount.text = "\(likes) Likes"
            keyPost.updateChildValues(update)  
        }
        ref.removeAllObservers()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
    cell.postID = self.posts[indexPath.row].postID
    cell.likecount.text! = "\(self.posts[indexPath.row].likes!) Likes"
    cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.posts[indexPath.row].pathToImage), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCells are reusable, so they are loaded and disposed of quite quickly when scrolling. You can't just update the value in the cell and expect it to be stored.

You need to update the data that is providing information to the tableView. So when that particular cell is reloaded, in `cellForRowAt` it can set the correct value.

If you are storing this information in Firebase, you may need to reload the data after updating. Show your cellForRowAt function for a more accurate answer

EDIT:

Okay, so your issue is that you have some results which have come from Firebase stored in `self.posts` but you update the Firebase version with `keyPost.updateChildValues(update)`. Whenever you do this you need to update self.posts with the updated data.

Comment: The same way that you set `self.posts` more than likely. I haven't used firebase in while. I'll check the docs

Answer (score 0):

Your cells are re-used, so don't rely on your local variables.
instead, you should have an object that you pass to your cell when you initialize the cell.

*in your cell, Create a setup function

```
setup(object: whatever) { 
   self.object = object 
   self.numberOfLikesLabel.text = object.numberOfLikes
   // set whatever other value
 }
```

*in cell for row at, call the function and pass the object.

when modifying values from your cell, set them in the object. Objects (classes) are passed by reference and not copied. so if you change it from your cell, you're also changing the same object in the view controller that has your tableView. so when the cell is re-used, and your setup function is called, you set your latest values.

EDIT: Explaining more

say you make an Object like so:

```
Class whatever {
    var numberOfLikes: Int = 0
}
```

This is a class. so if in your cellForRowAt you do

```
let cell = getmyCell() 
cell.setup(object: cellModel)
return cell
```

the cellModel that you passed, is passed by reference(by memory address)

So when you modify object's numberOfLikes from your cell, you are changing it in the viewController that has your tableview as well.

of course in your main view controller you also need to create your cellModel and store it as a class variable before cellForRowAt is called

so when your cell is getting reloaded, the same object is passed to it, with your updated values

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: please can you explain it better?

Comment: read the last comment of Scriptable.My problem is the array posts isn't updated . how resolve this?

Comment: when you get your post in 
if let post = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {}
you are not updating your self.posts array to have the new post object

Comment: I know  but how resolve this?because The array posts is in an another viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

**Update** your `posts[index_value].likes` when changing like count for which you want to update your likes count. you need to update `self.posts` with the updated data.

```
 @IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        self.like.isEnabled = false
        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        let keyPost = ref.child("posts").child(self.postID)
        keyPost.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let post = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                var likes = post["likes"] as! Int
                likes = likes+1

                let tag = (sender as AnyObject).tag
                // tag is an index value for your posts array on which index value u want to update likes count
                self.posts[tag].likes =  likes 

                let update = ["likes" : likes]
                self.likecount.text = "\(likes) Likes"
                keyPost.updateChildValues(update)  
            }
        ref.removeAllObservers()
    }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PostCell", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
        cell.postID = self.posts[indexPath.row].postID
        cell.likecount.text! = "\(self.posts[indexPath.row].likes!) Likes"
        cell.postImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.posts[indexPath.row].pathToImage), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))

        return cell
    }
```

**Edit:**

```
var likesObj = [Int: String]()


 @IBAction func likePressed(_ sender: Any) {
            self.like.isEnabled = false
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            let keyPost = ref.child("posts").child(self.postID)
            keyPost.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                if let post = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                    var likes = post["likes"] as! Int
                    likes = likes+1

                    let tag = (sender as AnyObject).tag
                    // tag is an index value for your posts array on which index value u want to update likes count
                    self.likesObj[tag ] = likes 

                    let update = ["likes" : likes]
                    self.likecount.text = "\(likes) Likes"
                    keyPost.updateChildValues(update)  
                }
            ref.removeAllObservers()
        }

        }
```

in your another `ViewController` where `self.posts` pass `likesObj` and Update your `self.postes` `likes`

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for (key, value) in likesObj{
            self.posts[key].value
        }
    }
```

Comment: but posts is in another viewcontroller

Comment: then save your likes count value in a objects and when your another 1viewController1 present update values for `self.posts`.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: read the last comment of Scriptable.My problem is the array posts isn't updated . how resolve this?

Comment: ok so why don't you implement a method for `keyPost.observeSingleEvent` to get the like count after you updated on firebase then update your like values in `self.posts`